# Laravel, llamar metodo adicional del Modelo en consulta Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

En mi modelo Deegre tengo un metodo fullName() que retorna string

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Deegre extends Model
{

public function fullName(){

    $level = [
        "1" => "Primer ",
        "2" => "Segundo ",
        "3" => "Tercer ",
        "4" => "Cuarto ",
        "5" => "Quinto ",
        "6" => "Sexto ",
    ];
   return $this->code . $level[$this->type] . " Grado de Secundaria";
}
```

Yo quiero llamar fullName() en mi consulta eloquent

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Deegre;

class DeegreRepository
{
 public function index(){
   return Deegre::where("year", now()->year)->get();
    // aqui quiero que mi metodo fullName sea llamado :(
 }

}
```

lo que deseo es llamar el metodo fullName que he creado en mi consulta, osea que por cada registro que trae tambiem me traiga  el valor de mi metodo, Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿qué error aparece al intentar llamarlo y cómo lo estás llamando?

Comment: No aparece error, lo que deseo es llamar el metodo fullName que he creado en mi consulta, osea que por cada registro que trae tambiem me traiga mi el valor de mi metodo

Comment: ¿cómo lo has intentado?

Comment: quiero algo asi, Deegre::with("fullName")->where("year", now()->year)->get(); Pero se que no se puede porque no es una relacion :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es un Accesor, para darle formato al valor que entrega la consulta, para esto debes utilizar la convención de Laravel que implica darle un nombre al método iniciando con `get` y terminando con `Attribute`:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    $level = [
        "1" => "Primer ",
        "2" => "Segundo ",
        "3" => "Tercer ",
        "4" => "Cuarto ",
        "5" => "Quinto ",
        "6" => "Sexto ",
    ];
    return $this->code . $level[$this->type] . " Grado de Secundaria";
}
```

Para utilizarlo simplemente lo llamas `$result->full_name`, después de haber realizado la consulta.

---

Según la información recibida posteriormente en los comentarios, para agregar el accesor a la respuesta json, se utiliza appends en el modelo:

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

Comment: Gracias, como llamaria en una coleccion con ->get() ya que cuando utilizo first() o find() me funciona

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer... por favor lee bien, primero se hace la consulta y luego se llama el Accesor.

Comment: Envio a Vue.js una coleccion de Deegre en json, y mi accesor no aparece,

Comment: Respuesta editada, la importancia de poner el contexto completo al momento de realizar una pregunta.